# Java Program GUI to develop java Programs without typing coding

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin

Is there any Java GUI available to develop java programs without typing single line of java code  and using GUI mode?

Comment: You want to develop GUIs or whole programs?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "develop".

Comment: whole program in GUI,for user should not aware of java,they should not see java code but they should able to develop java source like after giving neccessary values(Main Method) if they click some button like "generate" the GUI should generate a java file and store in system.

Comment: What kind of Java program do you want to develop with this GUI?  Or is this just a "does such a tool exist" question?

Answer (score 0):

No GUI in Java but you can use an open source content-management-system (CMS) example : Jahia, Hippo, Liferay, EXo Platform, Ametys, Magnolia, OpenCms ...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want the code to be generated without having to know the syntax and libraries of Java in a way similar that you can generate HTML based web pages using some CMS tools.

Let me ask you here: How would you define your business requirements in such a case using a tool?

There are tools which can generate quite a bit of Java code. e.g. IntelliJ can generate Data objects in a Hibernate/JPA based application if you can provide the data schema and a way to connect to the database, all of your favorite IDEs can generate boilerplate code like getters/setters/equals/hashcode etc.

Also, most of the modern IDEs can generate skeleton Java code and required configuration if you provide the frameworks you want to use like Spring, Hibernate, REST etc., but there is no direct way to generate business logic as there is no way for a tool to know what your business goals are.

Answer (score 0):

I fear there isn't way to develop an application whitout coding. You could install a business-oriented applicazion like Liferay or other good CMS, but the question is always "Could this application do all you will need in future?"

I think if you have simple and flexibles needs you could, maybe related with web site world tring to use one of these solution could solve. In general I say You probably need to write some line of code anytime.

If you are thinking to some of "more custom" than a simple web site, or a content based application, try to eplore some scaffolding tool like [play framework](http://www.playframework.com/), that can do easily lot of things, reducing programming load.